# What does と一体 mean in this sentence

Tags: grammar, translation

> だから、普段は小指さん、自分は”小指である”なんて意識もなく、持ち主の人と一体となっているのですが。。。。。。持ち主の人が寝ている時なんか、ふっと小指としてだけの意識になったりします。

Context: The previous sentence talks about how the little finger is just one part of the body, rather than an independent individual.

My translation of this is:

> Instead of being conscious of him being just a little finger(a part of something bigger), the little finger thinks of himself as a single body, along with the owner (my hazy understanding of that と). But when the owner sleeps, he thinks of himself suddenly as an independent little finger(小指としてだけ）.

Does that seem right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**～と一体【いったい】となる** is a set phrase that means "to become one with ～", "to behave as one (set) with ～", "to act in unison with ～", "to be fully integrated with ～", etc.

> - 宇宙と一体となる to become one with the universe
> - リーダーと一体となって行動しなさい。 Behave in unison with your leader.
> - 持ち主の人と一体となる to become one with the owner (person)

So the sentence says the little finger behaves only as part of the owner when the owner is awake. When the owner is asleep, sometimes the little finger gains its own consciousness.

Comment: I'm sorry. May I ask a dumb question?  ”持ち主の人が寝ている時なんか、ふっと小指としてだけの意識になったりします。” refers to "Only when the owner is asleep" or "For instance, when the owner is asleep"? And "sometimes" refers to "ふっと"？

Comment: @kimiTanaka I was not trying to give a full literal translation. Anyway I used "sometimes" because both なんか and たり indicate there is some uncertainty.

Comment: Thank you for the reply since I was wondering the combination
 of なんか、ふっと、 and たり. Thanks a lot.